# html div in height (%)

Tags: css, html, height

Hi I have problem with html height.

My height is now set to pixels and everything is okay. But when I put it in percentages it's not showing:

I need to height to fit my screen too as width do.

Here is the [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/Denonth/Qv5GU/)

What I want is to change `left` and `right` div's heights to a percentage to fit the screen.
When I do it my div disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv5GU/35/). I changed the CSS this way:

```
html, body 
{ 
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0 ;
 border: 0 none;
}

#footer
{
clear:both;
text-align:center;
background-color:#4671D5;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 100px 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 100px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 50px;
}
#left
{
background-color:red;
height:100%;
width:80%;
float:left;
}
#right
{
background-color:blue;
 float:left;
 width:20%;
 margin:0;
  height:100%;
}
#header
 {
 background-color:#4671D5;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 100px 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px 50px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 100px 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px 50px;
    height: 100%;
 }
 #container
 {
 width:98%;
 padding-left:1%;
 padding-right:1%;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

It works. :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course they disappear. Divs or any element which has `display: block` by default have 100% width and auto height (defined by its content) so when you say you want 50% height that doesn't mean anything because 50% of auto is 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set inner div's height in percent then you have to set it's parent height first and then your inner divs will occupy the assigned percent of height of it's parent container.

```
#container {
    width:98%;
    height:570px;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
}
```

`#left{ height:100% }` will measure it's height depending on it's parent div`#container` height.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Qv5GU/31/)
​

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but I would have thought this is what you were looking for as it grows and shrinks with the size of the window. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gusper/Qv5GU/41/) for it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">Header</div>
            <div id="left">Left</div>
            <div id="right">Right</div>
            <div id="footer"> Footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

​
Here's the CSS:

```
html, body 
{ 
    height:100%;
}
#container
{
    height: 100%;
    width:98%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
}
#header
{
    height:10%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#footer
{
    height: 10%;
    clear:both;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#left
{
    background-color:red;
    height:80%;
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}
#right
{
    background-color:green;
    height:80%;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
```